# What are all the Doctor Who works that reference the Library of St John the Beheaded

Tags: doctor-who

The Fandom page on [the Library of St John the Beheaded](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Library_of_St_John_the_Beheaded) contains *many* citations from Doctor Who works, but I don't know if it's exhaustive.

What are all the Doctor Who works that reference this in-universe library?

Answer (score 1):

Here are all the references I can find:

### TV

- Extremis
- Cold War

### Prose

- All-Consuming Fire
- Millennial Rites
- The Empire of Glass
- Christmas on a Rational Planet
- Dragons' Wrath
- The Quantum Archangel
- The Medusa Effect
- Theatre of War
- Tears of the Oracle
- The Doomsday Manuscript
- The Two-Level Effect
- The Secret Lives of Monsters

### Audio

- The Ship of a Billion Years
- Neverland
- No Place Like Home

Comment: I used some javascript to grab these titles, but I may have missed some from the page linked in the question